# How to rotate text and position it properly? (CSS, HTML)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a rotated headline next to some text. Statically it works very easy with absolute positioning (left picture). I have, however, difficulties when the page gets resized and the positioning fails (right picture).

[image: Relative positioning]
[image: Fails when you resize]

**Current CSS (can be changed):**

```
.headline {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 185px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

**Current HTML structure (can be changed):**

```
<header>
    <h1 class="headline">Über mich</h1>
</header>
<div class="text">
  <p class="introduction">....</p>
</div>
```

How can I position the element so that I always stays `20px` next to the paragraph?
Could someone link me to existing patterns how to solve this?

A solution with JS (and jQuery) would an option, I would, however, obviously prefer CSS.

Comment: Show your markup using fiddle couldn't get your problem presize

Comment: had that issue two. I was digging a bit deeper in it and could not find a real explanation for it. The strange part is that width and height are »rotated« and if the rotation center is at the upper left at the beginning, it is at the bottom left if you rotate 270° counter clockwise. Than you would need to set the top to the width of the `<h1>`, probably the easiest thing is to align right, set the transform origin to the upper-right edge and rotate 90° counter clockwise. But honestly, that is just kind of guesing

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `transform-origin` via `transform-origin: center;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was a combination of Diego's answer and Smamatti's comment:

I had to use `transform-origin:bottom` and `width:0`. That was working rather quickly, the big problem I had was positioning the text independently to the length of the text. I've only managed to do this by using javascript.

```
.header
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    transform-origin: bottom; 
    margin-top: 280px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Javascript (to ensure compatibility to variables text length):

```
function adjustSideHeader() {

//check if the headline is visible
  if($('h1.headline').length > 0)
  {
    var headline = $('h1.headline')[0];
    var stringLength = headline.textContent.length;
    //add style tag to support media queries
    document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
       "h1.headline { margin-top: " + (stringLength*23.5) + "px; -webkit-transition: margin-top 2s; transition: margin-top 2s;}"
  }    
}

// fire it when document is loaded
$(document).ready(setTimeout(adjustSideHeader, 300));
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. Managed to solve it like this in pure CSS :

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  left: 30px; /* change this value to match needs */
  top: 30px; /* change this value to match needs */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried moving

```
<h1 class="headline">Über mich</h1>
```

inside

```
<div class="text">?
```

and set

```
.text {
    position: relative;
}
```

so that the position is relative to to "text" div. After that you might want to move the Über mich text to the left by reducing it's left value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried use `position:relative` and the `margin` property?, I suppose it would be something like this:

```
.headline {
     white-space: nowrap;
     position: relative; //changed
     margin-top: 185px; //changed
     margin-left: -20px; //changed
     transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

*Note: I think you should move the  headline inside the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that may be late but worked wonderfully for me.

Normally your text will have a class or id and it will be position:absolute, and positioning values after it, like so:

```
.TextClass{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:55%;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
```

etc.

However, when you rotate, the positioning becomes relative (as mentioned above).

I found out that by simply putting the rotated text inside a parent div, you can position the (unrotated, position absolute) parent div as much as you want, and then rotate the text (which will be position:relative) inside the parent div, like so:

```
.divname{
    position:absolute;
    top:50vh;
    left:50vw;
}
.TextClass{
    position:relative;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```